# How to reach the desired Non functional requirements

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

im new to perf testing,i have to run some performance tests and have already created the scripts and infra- running distributed testing with gcp Vms

i have been given the the nfrs buti should use minute wise data (transactions done in a minute ) for the load

e.g  this are the active users and bets placed per minute,i have minute data for about 2 hrs
[image]

how can one configure jmeter to the minute-wise data,i did the conversion to get the hourly and then distribute the load concurrently  but been told that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) it allows specifying the desired load in terms of number of requests per minute

[image]

Be informed of the following:

1. Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the threads in order to **limit** JMeter's [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) execution rate to the desired number of requests per minute
2. Despite word `Constant` it its name it doesn't have to be "Constant", you can put a [JMeter Variable or Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into the "Target Throughput" field and amend it according to your [workload mode](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/how-define-right-workload-model-your-performance-tests)l as required in the runtime.